# what plugin to add to support ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider, grails 3

Tags: grails

what plugin to support ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. I am using grails 3.X. i added thin in build.groovy "compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:3.0.2'"

this is in resource.groovy as explin in this url: [Grails Spring Security LDAP plugin with multiple Active Directory servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218684/grails-spring-security-ldap-plugin-with-multiple-active-directory-servers)

grails:
plugin:
springsecurity:
ldap:
providerNames: 'ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider'

getting error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider for class: resources
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
at resources$_run_closure1.doCall(resources.groovy:4)

Comment: beans = {
//LDAP authentication
ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider,
'domainName',"LDAP://serverurl")}

Comment: that lines in resource.groovy

Comment: is it possible to use ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthentic‌​ationProvider with groovy and grails 3 app. or it is just for java